# Software de comparação entre frameworks php

Tags: php, engenharia-de-software, testes, framework, testes-funcionais

Boa noite galera.

Alguém pode me indicar alguns softwares de comparação de frameworks php? Softwares que comparam desempenho, tempo de resposta, tempo de carregamento, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Se tiver o Apache** instalado na sua máquina, então pode usar o comando de linha `ab` ([**ApacheBench**](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/ab.html)), supondo que esteja em pastas, exemplo de uso (laravel):

```
ab -n 1000 -c 10 http://localhost/laravel/
```

Codeigniter:

```
ab -n 1000 -c 10 http://localhost/codeigniter/
```

Em windows o comando não deve estar global, se tiver Xampp, Wamp ou EasyPHP com apache (tem variações com Nginx que não vai ter o `ab`) então navegue via cmd até a pasta, algo como:

```
cd c:\xampp\apache2\bin
ab -n 1000 -c 10 http://localhost/laravel/
```

Isso vai testar requisições por segundo que de uma URL, então pode apontar para a que desejar.

Após executar o comando terá um resultado semelhante a isto:

```
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 1373084 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking localhost (be patient)
Completed 100 requests
Completed 200 requests
Completed 300 requests
Completed 400 requests
Completed 500 requests
Completed 600 requests
Completed 700 requests
Completed 800 requests
Completed 900 requests
Completed 1000 requests
Finished 1000 requests


Server Software:        Apache/2.4.3
Server Hostname:        localhost
Server Port:            80

Document Path:          /laravel/
Document Length:        11 bytes

Concurrency Level:      10
Time taken for tests:   158.097 seconds
Complete requests:      1000
Failed requests:        0
Write errors:           0
Total transferred:      1008148 bytes
HTML transferred:       11000 bytes
Requests per second:    6.33 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       1580.966 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       158.097 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          6.23 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    0   0.5      0       1
Processing:   764 1565 1190.0   1371   15672
Waiting:      764 1564 1190.0   1369   15671
Total:        765 1566 1190.0   1371   15672

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%   1371
  66%   1485
  75%   1558
  80%   1622
  90%   1846
  95%   2075
  98%   4949
  99%   9404
 100%  15672 (longest request)
executed: ab -n 1000 -c 10 "http://localhost/laravel/"
```

Você pode ter um comparativo geral, mas neste tipo de resultado o que mais observo é esta linha:

```
Requests per second:    6.33 [#/sec]
```

Traduzindo seria "requisições por segundo", então quanto mais requisições em um segundo é melhor.

---

Existe um software em Python semelhante, chamado [**boom**](https://pypi.org/project/boom/), para instalar é necessário o `pip`:

```
pip install boom
```

Uso se for em pastas:

```
boom http://localhost/laravel/ -c 10 -n 100
```

O resultado será algo semelhante a isto:

```
Server Software: Apache/2.4.3 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.0.1c
Running GET http://127.0.0.1:80/laravel/
Running 1000 queries - concurrency 10
[================================================================>.] 99% Done

-------- Results --------
Successful calls                1000
Total time                      185.2391 s
Average                         1.7943 s
Fastest                         0.6926 s
Slowest                         30.1822 s
Amplitude                       29.4896 s
Standard deviation              2.527278
RPS                             5
BSI                             :(

-------- Status codes --------
Code 200                        1000 times.

-------- Legend --------
RPS: Request Per Second
BSI: Boom Speed Index
```

Alguns detalhes:

- RPS, como diz a legenda, significa requisições por segundo
- BSI se refere a uma avaliação própria do comando, ele pode retornar os seguintes valores:

  1. Se as requisições por segundo forem maior que 500: `Woooooo Fast`
  2. Se as requisições por segundo for de 101 a 500: `Pretty good`
  3. Se as requisições por segundo for de 51 a 100: `Meh`
  4. Se as requisições por segundo for menor que 51: `:(`

Comment: Bom dia. Obrigado pelos esclarecimentos. Isso irá me ajudar e muito.